# ¿Cómo setear valores en una propiedad que es un array y es del tipo enum?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde debo serializar una clase en un Json, en esta clase existe una propiedad que es un arreglo y el tipo es enum,

Este es el atributo y la propiedad:

```
private FacturaElectronicaMedioPago[] medioPagoField;

 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MedioPago")]
    public FacturaElectronicaMedioPago[] MedioPago {
        get {
            return this.medioPagoField;
        }
        set {
            this.medioPagoField = value;
        }
    }
```

Esta es la definicion de FacturaElectronicaMedioPago:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica")]

public enum FacturaElectronicaMedioPago {

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("01")]
    Item01,

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("02")]
    Item02,

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("03")]
    Item03,

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("04")]
    Item04,

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("05")]
    Item05,

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("99")]
    Item99,
}
```

escribi esto pero me devuelve este error : El tipoproporcionado debe ser Enum
¿Como puedo hacerlo correctamenta?

```
 MedioPago = (FacturaElectronicaMedioPago[])Enum.Parse(typeof(FacturaElectronicaMedioPago[]), "Item02")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes hacer el `Enum.Parse` al tipo `FacturaElectronicaMedioPago` (Enum), y no al Tipo `FacturaElectronicaMedioPago[]`:

```
MedioPago = (FacturaElectronicaMedioPago)Enum.Parse(typeof(FacturaElectronicaMedioPago), "Item02");
```

Answer (score 1):

Enum.Parse retorna un objeto, no un array del enum. Intenta inicializando un array pasandole el valor del Enum.Parse:

```
 MedioPago  = new FacturaElectronicaMedioPago[] { (FacturaElectronicaMedioPago)Enum.Parse(typeof(FacturaElectronicaMedioPago), "Item0") }
```